# Issue with Serverless deploy of smart contract-Dependency mismatch -Package.json,Package-lock.json error

Tags: truffle, aws

I'm trying to deploy my smart contract serverless(AWS lambda) and I'm using Truffle framework.

The code is getting deployed in an earlier system(earlier it was deployed here). Now I have updated the smart contract version .When I am deploying it. I am not able to in my new system due to dependencies mismatch n version change.I tested my smart contract in local system using ganache. there uts working fine. When deploying serverless I am getting the issue.

Below is the error screenshot

[image]
 - Below are the dependencies in package.json.

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.256.1",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"openzeppelin-solidity": "^1.12.0",
"pug": "^2.0.3",
"solc": "^0.4.24",
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.50"
```

and all the above have been updated to newer versions..
0

above were the earlier dependencies in which the project was executible.Now I have updated to below dependencies--
"aws-sdk": "^2.489.0", "express": "^4.17.1", "fs": "0.0.2", "openzeppelin-solidity": "^2.3.0", "pug": "^2.0.4", "solc": "^0.5.10", "truffle": "^5.0.26", "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.13", "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.52" } even though the package.json file is updated the package-lock.json file is in the older version ...n despite several tries (using ncu -u -->npm install)..still package-lock is not getting updated

Answer (score 1):

Try to Upgrade web3 to 1.0.0-beta55 and add "null" as second parameter like this

const web3 = new Web3('http://......', **null**, options);

Comment: above were the earlier dependencies in which the project was executible .Now I have updated  to below dependencies--    "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.489.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^2.3.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "solc": "^0.5.10",
    "truffle": "^5.0.26",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.13",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.52"
  }
}

Comment: "^1.0.0-beta.52" this "^" is tricky, what i know that web3 added the "null" in the current versions , sorry cant help more without seeing your code